# nvd3 - Format Milliseconds to h:m:s in Chart (Period of Time, not Date)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I've managed to display Dates in d3/ nvd3 charts, which i did like this passing a value of milliseconds:

```
chart.xAxis
     .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%e, %H:%M')(new Date(d))
});
```

I'd like to display the Milliseconds as a Period of Time on the y-axis, like "6 h : 23 min : 5 sec".

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Muff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`d3.time.format('%H h : %M min : %S sec')(new Date())`

it will format the date like this

**05 h : 34 min : 26 sec**

Or if you don't like the 0 padding for hours do

`d3.time.format('%-H h : %M min : %S sec')(new Date())`

it will format the date like this

**5 h : 37 min : 54 sec**

**EDIT**

IN such a case you will need to put an if block to do the check and return the desired format something like this:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
       var date = new Date(d);
       if (date.getHours() == 0){ 
         return d3.time.format('%M min : %S sec')(d)
       } else {
         return d3.time.format('%-H h : %M min : %S sec')(d)
       }

}
```

Comment: This works with one disatvantage: When i have a period that is below an hour like e.g. 21258 Milliseconds it converts to "1 h : 00 min : 21 sec". Is there a way to display 'h' and 'min' only if there's a value for them?

Comment: Mh i'm sorry, when i use this i get the error: `TypeError: d.getHours is not a function
    at d3_time_formats.H (d3js_d3.js?hash=54da9a2…:2643)`. Any clue?

Comment: Is d a date instance? then you dont need to to do new Date(d)

Comment: i found the error -  a.)it must be date instead of d in your solution in the if/ else statement b.) the hours seem to have a standard value of 1 so the first if staement is ignored, so the solution that works for me is: `var date = new Date(d);
   date.setHours(date.getHours()-1);
   console.log(date.getHours());
   if (date.getHours() === 0) {
    return d3.time.format('%M min : %S sec')(date)
   } else {
    return d3.time.format('%-H h : %M min : %S sec')(date)
   } `

Comment: why is hours set to 1 by default?